# Concatenating and Summing Cells Based On Mulitple Criteria From Two Different Worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

[Image of WorkSheet1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyalB.png) [Image of WorkSheet2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edkNF.png) What would the Excel VBA code look like if I wanted to sum cells in one column and concatenate cells in another column based on criteria in two different worksheets? In the example below, I want to sum the rates and concatenate the types in WorkSheet1 based on the following criteria:

1. If the description in WorkSheet1 matches the description in WorkSheet2
2. If the code in WorkSheet2 is 03
3. If the types in WorkSheet1 are "Income" and "Special Cash"

Here's what the worksheets look like before the VBA code runs:

WorkSheet1

```
        Column A        Column B               Column C
(Row 1) Description     Type                   Rate 
(Row 2) BGIO US Equity  Income                 0.05    
(Row 3) BGIO US Equity  Short Term Cap Gain    0.009573
(Row 4) BGIO US Equity  Special Cash           0.00931
```

WorkSheet2

```
        Column A         Column B    Column C
(Row 1) Description      Rate        Code  
(Row 2) BGIO US Equity   0.05931     03
(Row 3) BGIO US Equity   0.009573    07
```

Here's the result in WorkSheet1 after the VBA code runs:

```
        Column A       Column B               Column C
(Row 1) Description    Type                   Rate 
(Row 2) BGIO US Equity Income + Special Cash  0.05931 
(Row 3) BGIO US Equity Short Term Cap Gain    0.009573
```

Essentially, I am creating matches (if they exist) between the two worksheets for reconciliation purposes.

This is the VBA code I have so far that isn't working for the concatenation part:

```
For e = 2 To WorkSheet1LastRow
    checkValue = WorkSheet1.Cells(e, 1)
    For x = 2 To WorkSheet1LastRow
        Type = WorkSheet1.Cells(x, 2)
    Next x
Next e
For c = 2 To WorkSheet2LastRow
    CheckValue2 = WorkSheet2.cells(c, 1)
    For q = 2 To WorkSheet2LastRow
        If WorkSheet2.cells(q, 3) = "03" And WorkSheet2.Cells(q, 1) <> CheckValue2 Then
            If checkValue2 = CheckValue1 Then
                If Type = "Income" Or "Special Cash" Then
                    Type = Type & "+" & Type
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next q
Next c
```

I'm thinking if I can code this part successfully I can record a sumif formula to complete this process.

Comment: You could probably do that a lot easier with a couple worksheet formulas, unless there's a reason you need to do it in VBA.  (not to discourage anyone from learning!)

Comment: ...what would you like to `sumif`?  I'm actually not sure I follow what you're doing, but I suspect your sample data isn't representative of what you would actually have, because based on your criteria, `description` is irrelevant since there's only one, so you just need a `MATCH` and an `IF` .

Comment: I would really like to learn how to do this with VBA because if can see how this is done it will open me up to other innovation projects down the road.

Comment: there would be a lot more descriptions in that column I was just providing this example because if I can get that to go and add the other iterations later.

Comment: Yeah I figured there's be more descriptions, my point was that it's important to examples rat least *kind of* representative of the actual data, because from an outside perspective, two different people will often assume completely different things that will affect their interpretation of the solution.   ...But A+ for the excellent attitude about doing something tricky to learn VBA...  (Kind of the opposite of many new members asking questions: "I need this code fixed and I don't want to learn a thing... and I want it done *fast*."... it was *funny* the first couple hundred times,)

Comment: anyhow, I'm sure I could help if I better understood what you're trying to do next.  ie.,: `if I can code this part successfully I can record a sumif formula to complete this process.`  What do you mean? You can call worksheet functions like `sumif` from VBA if you want, like `x = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf( ..., ... )` -- except the cell references need to be passed as Range objects, ie., `Range("A1:A5")` , or, `Range(Cells(1,1), Cells(5,1))` etc

Answer (score 0):

This appears to do what you've described.

```
Option Explicit

Sub incomeSpecialCash()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim descRate As Variant

    With Worksheets(2)
        ReDim descRate(1 To Application.CountIf(.Columns("C"), 3), 1 To 2)
        j = LBound(descRate, 1)
        For i = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            If .Cells(i, "C").Text = "03" Then
                descRate(j, 1) = .Cells(i, "A").Value2
                descRate(j, 2) = .Cells(i, "B").Value2
                j = j + 1
            End If
        Next i
    End With

    With Worksheets(1)
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            For i = LBound(descRate, 1) To UBound(descRate, 1)
                .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=descRate(i, 1)
                .AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:="income"
                With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0)
                    If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Cells)) Then
                        Intersect(.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible), .Columns("C")) = descRate(i, 2)
                        Intersect(.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible), .Columns("B")) = "Income + Special Cash"
                    End If
                End With
                .AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:="special cash"
                With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0)
                    If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Cells)) Then
                        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
                    End If
                End With
            Next i
        End With
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a ton for showing me this array. I'm still struggling, however, if the number of rows varies with different securities.  I've provided 2 images of the root files I am trying to write dynamic code for that will follow the 3 criteria. Please click the blue link and the beginning of my original question. I also plan to add iteration’s for combination types other than “Income” and “Special Cash.” For example, the description CCT US Equity has the combinations “Regular Cash” and “Special Cash” on WorkSheet1 as well as a Code of “03” on WorkSheet2. Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: I think I have it working now. I'll let you know how this rest of my project goes. Thanks!